# How do write reg exp for string has structure like a-b-1 and a-b-1/d-e-2?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

Sorry my english is not good. I have a problem, I want to compare two different string use reg exp. The first string has structure like **a-b-1**, ex: mobile-phone-1. And the second string has structure like **a-b-1/d-e-2**, ex: mobile-phone-1/nokia-asha-23. How can I do it? You can use preg_match() method or something method ... This method for two different string. Thanks so much!

Code demo:

```
if (preg_match("reg exp 1", string1)) { // do something }
if (preg_match("reg exp 2", string2)) { // do something }
```

P/S: shouldn't care too much about code demo

Comment: what you mean by comparing two strings? with preg_match you compare string against regular expression and possibly split them. can you explain more about what you need?

Comment: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) will tell you. You'll also _learn_ a lot more when you do this yourself...

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem Thanks!

Comment: use `/^\w+-\w+-\d+$/` for first one and `/^\w+-\w+-\d+\/\w+-\w+-\d+$/` for second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '#[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+(/[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+)?#';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    return $matches;
}
```

To match the shorter string use:

```
$pattern = '#[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+#';
```

To match the longer:

```
$pattern = '#[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+/[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+#';
```

To match the longer with even more dashes:

```
$pattern = '#[\w]+-[\w]+-[\d]+/[\w-]+[\d]+#';
```

Comment: Excuse me! what kind of string can use this pattern? a-b-1 or a-b-1/d-e-2?

Comment: It can be used to detect both. The part in parenthesis has a question mark, because it's optional.

Comment: I want to have 2 patterns for 2 different strings, it can? not optional.

Comment: I had to go and just got back. I'll update my answer.

Comment: if I use long string as $string2 = 'a-b-1/d-c-c-c-c-c-c-3'; for the second case, it will not work

Comment: Ok. I put another pattern up there for even more dashes. I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match("/^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$/i",$string1))

if(preg_match("/^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$/i",$string2))
```

'i' in the end is for case sensitivity.

Comment: Plz, escape `/` symbol in the 2-nd regexp

Comment: Thanks. I'm only give an example but with long string I can't use it. Ex: a-b-c-d-3 for first string and e-a-b-c-d/b-d-e-r-f-4 and so on. I run you code and get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\preg_match.php

Comment: You have to change pattern of that. If you have long string, if(preg_match("/^([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$/i",$string1)),

Comment: And for error, check your syntax,

Comment: Excuse me! It doesn't work.

Comment: lolx....what is not working.

Comment: With $string1 = 'a-b-d-f-g-a-A-z-z-c-1'; and $string2 = 'a-b-1/d-c-c-c-c-c-c-3'; example there is nothing return, it means that it always not match. I try other string as $string1 = 'd-a-f' and $string2 = 'a-b-c-2/t-g-h-g-12', the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression with explanation. Solved by step by step.

```
$text1='mobile is for you--phone-341/nokia-asha-253'; //sample string 1
$text2='mobile-phone-341'; //sample string 2

  $regular_expression1='(\w)';  // Word             (mobile)
  $regular_expression2='(-)';   // Any Single Character         (-)
  $regular_expression3='(\w)';  // Word             (phone)
  $regular_expression4='(-)';   // Any Single Character         (-)
  $regular_expression5='(\d+)'; // Integer Number           (341)

  $regular_expression6='(\/)';  // Any Single Character         (/)

  $regular_expression7='(\w)';  // Word             (nokia)
  $regular_expression8='(-)';   // Any Single Character         (-)
  $regular_expression9='(\w)';  // Word             (asha)
  $regular_expression10='(-)';  // Any Single Character         (-)
  $regular_expression11='(\d)'; // Integer Number           (253)

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$regular_expression1.$regular_expression2.$regular_expression3.$regular_expression4.$regular_expression5.$regular_expression6.$regular_expression7.$regular_expression8.$regular_expression9.$regular_expression10.$regular_expression11."/is", $text1))
  {
    echo "a-b-1/d-e-2 format string";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not in a-b-1/d-e-2";
  }
  echo "<br>------------------------<br>"; //just for separation

 if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$regular_expression1.$regular_expression2.$regular_expression3.$regular_expression4.$regular_expression5."/is", $text2))
  {
    echo "a-b-1 formate string";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not in a-b-1 format";
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code but else case is always happend. My two strings can be $string1 = 'a-b-1', $string2 = 'a-b-1/d-c-c3'; or $string1 = 'a-b-d-f-g-a-A-z-z-c-1', $string2 = 'a-b-1/d-c-c-c-c-c-c-3' and so on.

Comment: @KillerWhale read this code well. it is very easy to understand how you can write your own regular expressions. it is very interesting.:)
I think you can achieve your need if you understand it. few changes only needed. Note: this two codes are for the format you specified in your question..

Comment: Oh! I'm really sorry about my failure. You are nice man.

Comment: I didn't read carefully what you wrote. Thanks for your help!